# Manga with artifacts/magical items that transform body parts into animals parts -> arm into dog head

Tags: story-identification, manga, animals, magical-items

I remember reading the first tome, and it's a story with artefacts or magic objects that give powers and I remember one gave arm expansion or strength, it was an arm brace or something.

I also remember an ear ring. I think there were a theme around their durability. I think there was a dog and actually I think the arm brace transformed the arm of the boy who wore it into a dog head.

I'm sorry, it's very cloudy in my memory. I also remember a man with a afro and a girl with ear rings giving her bunny parts. The art style included a lot of dark maybe because the action took place mostly at night.